# Python: Django framework using MySql database

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I'm planning to use **Django framework** for one of my projects. I've installed Django, watched some tutorials and now I'm trying to create a web server which will use a **MySql** database.

To begin with, I have a made a database with **phpMyAdmin** from xampp and now I want to use the data stored in that database and just to print some entries from that database.

- What should I do in order to do that?
- how can I use a mysql database with django?

On the tutorial, it was used sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using python3, I found that the best option is use `pymysql` importing it in the settings file like so

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

with `django.db.backends.mysql` set as the `ENGINE`.

I would also advise against using a pre-populated database: Django is very good at building tables, and I'm sure you read about `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

If you want to manually populate the database, you could use a small script or [hop in the shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) to do that before fetching and presenting data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL as your database. In order to do this, you need to change your settings.py file with appropriate settings for MySQL:

```
ENGINE=django.db.backends.mysql
NAME='schema-name'
USER='username'
PASSWORD='password'
HOST='localhost'
PORT='3306'
```

With these settings, your django application should be able to talk to MySQL database. You can also verify by running `python manage.py syncdb` command from the command prompt in your project folder. Further information regarding the databases can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install MySql for python using `pip` which can be found [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html). After installing `pip` say `pip install MySQL-python`. Hopefully it should get you started with MySql. But you might also want to use Mysql python connector which can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/).Be aware of the Python version you are using then download the connector.You might also want to install through which can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html) which will install with all pre-requisites like Python connector and server,etc..

### in settings.py file

you need to change DATABASES

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',               
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',   # Use this if Database exists in your PC or replace it by IP address of PC where you are fetching the Database
        'PORT': '3306',     
    },

    'mydb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',                  
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',           # Use this if Database exists in your PC or replace it by IP address of PC where you are fetching the Database
        'PORT': '3306',     
        }
}
```

after which you should be able to access the MySql database.
Also import MySql in your database file as `import MySQLdb`